# Create an user in Firebase without automatically login

Tags: flutter, dart

I have wrote a code, which should avoid the automatically login when an user get created.

The code worked until I used the dart migration tool. Now when I use this code with null-safety, then the secondaryApp is not created and another user get logged in.

Can someone please explain me, what I am doing wrong? I need to fix this code as fast as possible, but I just can't find the mistake.

I really appreciate any help.

**code login:**

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () async {
    await authProvider.signUpUser(
         usernameController.text.trim(),
         emailController.text.trim(),
         passwordController.text.trim(),
         firstNameController.text.trim(),
         lastNameController.text.trim(),
         _birthDateInString,
         _genderSelected);
    })
```

**code (database request):**

```
Future<bool> signUpUser(String username, String email, String password,
      String firstName, String lastName, String? birthday, String? gender) async {
    try {
      _status = Status.Authenticating;
      notifyListeners(); //changing status

      FirebaseApp secondaryApp = await Firebase.initializeApp(
        name: 'Secondary',
        options: Firebase.app().options,
      );

      try {
        UserCredential? credential = await FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(
                app: secondaryApp)
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
            .then((result) async {
          //User user = result.user;
          _userServices.createUser(
            uid: result.user!.uid,
            username: username,
            email: email,
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            birthday: birthday,
            gender: gender,
            status: 'aktiv',
            role: 'User',
          );
        });
        print('user created');

        await credential?.user!.sendEmailVerification();
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
      print('secondapp deleted');
      await secondaryApp.delete();
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
      notifyListeners();
      print('secondapp deleted');

      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
      notifyListeners();
      print(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little difficult to completely debug your project without a little more context but I tried to clean up just a bit and add a few print statements to help you out, hope this helps :)

```
Future<bool> signUpUser(
    String username,
    String email,
    String password,
    String firstName,
    String lastName,
    String? birthday,
    String? gender,
    ) async {
  try {
    _status = Status.Authenticating;
    notifyListeners(); //changing status

    FirebaseApp secondaryApp = await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: 'Secondary',
      options: Firebase.app().options,
    );

    /// here is our user:)
    var _user;

    try {
      UserCredential? credential = await FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: secondaryApp)
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

      print('we got our credentials lets take a look to see if we have them ${credential}');
      var uid = credential.user?.uid;
      if (uid != null) {
        _userServices.createUser(
          uid: uid,
          username: username,
          email: email,
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          birthday: birthday,
          gender: gender,
          status: 'aktiv',
          role: 'User',
        );
        print('user created');
      }

      _user = credential?.user;
      if (_user != null) {
        await credential?.user.sendEmailVerification();
        print('done with our send email verification!');
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    if (_user != null) {
      /// this means that we successfully authenticated our user consider returning from the function right here!!
    }
    
    print('secondapp deleted');
    await secondaryApp.delete();
    _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    notifyListeners();
    print('secondapp deleted');

    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    notifyListeners();
    print(e.toString());
    return false;
  }
}
```

One other thing that I noticed with your code is that if a User successfully authenticates then you automatically delete your secondaryApp. Is this your desired behavior?

I went ahead and added a note for you to add some code in there if you want but didn't want to dramatically change your code.

Comment: Yeah, I want to create a normaler user as admin and not get automatically logged in after creating this normal user. That's the reason why I delete the secondaryApp